# ko.toJSON and ko.toJS returning empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using jquery and jquery validate in my form.  I have no issues with either all is working as expected.  I am new to knockout.js however.  I am trying to using knockout.js to pass the data to a web api that I have wrote.  I am having an issues with using knockout.js to convert the form data to either JSON or simple java script data.  The calls that I am making are ko.toJSON and ko.toJS, in either case the data is not initialized when looking in the debugger.

Why is the call to ko.JSON and the call to ko.toJS not returning the values set in my form?  The following is my script block:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
        });

        $("#inside-form").validate({
            "errorclass": 'ui-state-error-test',
            "highlight": function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).addClass("ui-state-error");
            },
            "unhighlight": function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).removeClass("ui-state-error");
            },
            rules:
                {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required"
                },
            messages:
                {
                    firstname: "Please enter your name",
                    lastname: "Please enter your name"
                },
            submitHandler: function () {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this course?")) {
                    //console.log("firstname = " + )
                    console.log($("#firstnamefield").val());
                    var jdata = ko.toJSON(this.data);
                    var jdat1a = ko.toJS(data);
                    //Todo insert jquery ajax call here
                }
            }
        });

        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.firstname = ko.observable();
            self.lastname = ko.observable();
            self.street1 = ko.observable();
            self.street2 = ko.observable();
        };

        var data = new ViewModel();

        ko.applyBindings(data); // This makes Knockout get to work

        var validator = $("#inside-form").validate();
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the methods are not returning data is that you aren't passing any data in to them.  If you console.log(this.data); and/or console.log(data); you will see that both are null before you are trying to unwrap them.

You need to have access to the data for that to work.

Consider creating a function to handle your view model logic instead of an anonymous event handler - it is the MVVM approach.  Example -

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstname = ko.observable();
    self.lastname = ko.observable();
    self.street1 = ko.observable();
    self.street2 = ko.observable();
    self.submitData = function () {
        var thisData = ko.toJS(self);
        // Put your ajax call here
    };
};
```

Note that the above is more or less pseudo-code (calling toJS on self will result in the function being converted as well, and probably will result in a circular reference)

Comment: Thanks!  My problem wasn't this code at all it was the fact that I didn't add the data-bindings in the html on the <input> elements.